# How to call javascript function for local storage from C# code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have javascript file to store user data in local storage. For some reason I need to call javascript code from C# code behind or from html page of site.

Here is my javascript code:

```
   LocalStorage.setItem("TestUser", JSON.stringify(
     {
       "Usr_UserAvatar": “Avartar”,
       "Usr_Username": “The username (string)”,
       "Usr_Email": “Email (string)”,
       "Usr_FirstName": “First name (string)”,
       "Usr_LastName": “Last name (string)”,
       "Usr_CompanyName": “Company name (string)”,
       "Usr_CountryCode": “Country code (string)”,
       "isAdmin": “If the user has admin rights (boolean)” 
     }
   });
```

How can I call this code form C# code behind? Please guide me how to do this.Thanks.

Comment: So you're setting in Local Storage on the *client machine* whether they have admin rights or not? What if the client just decides to change `isAdmin`?

Answer (score 1):

First, your question has nothing to do with `LocalStorage`. You just want to run some JavaScript code from ASP.NET.

Consider you are using WebForms, which I suppose because you used the expression `Code behind`, you could just do what @Angus said. Register a function in a client `.js` file and run it using [RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Alternatively, you could simply put this somewhere in your `ASPX` file, `Masterpage` or `RazorView`:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
   LocalStorage.setItem("TestUser", JSON.stringify(
     {
       "Usr_UserAvatar": “Avartar”,
       "Usr_Username": “The username (string)”,
       "Usr_Email": “Email (string)”,
       "Usr_FirstName": “First name (string)”,
       "Usr_LastName": “Last name (string)”,
       "Usr_CompanyName": “Company name (string)”,
       "Usr_CountryCode": “Country code (string)”,
       "isAdmin": “If the user has admin rights (boolean)” 
     }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClientScriptManager to call your javascript function from C# code behind.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    Page.GetType(), 
    "test", 
    "FunctionName();", 
    true);
```